# Cygwin: import numpy error

Tags: python, cygwin

I am trying to `import numpy` in Cygwin. I get the following error message.

I have `numpy 1.11.2-1`, a.k.a. the `python2-numpy: Python scientific computing module` package, installed through the Cygwin installer. I also have `Python 2.7.14-1`, a.k.a. the `python2: Python 2 language interpreter` package also installed through Cygwin. I don't have a local installation of Python on my machine.

```
$ python
Python 2.7.14 (default, Oct 31 2017, 21:12:13)
[GCC 6.4.0] on cygwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import numpy
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/__init__.py", line 142, in <module>
    from . import add_newdocs
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/add_newdocs.py", line 13, in <module>
    from numpy.lib import add_newdoc
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/lib/__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
    from .type_check import *
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/lib/type_check.py", line 11, in <module>
    import numpy.core.numeric as _nx
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/core/__init__.py", line 14, in <module>
    from . import multiarray
ImportError: No such file or directory
```

There seem to be a number of posts on this but all lacking a solution that works for me. I tried restarting my computer per https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42320132/not-able-to-import-numpy-in-cygwin, but that did not work.

I have also edited my `$PATH` variable:

```
$ echo $PATH
/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/:/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/:/usr/bin
```

Comment: you should ask on stackoverflow. much larger community, and relevant to stackoverflow

Comment: In reality it was relevant here as it is not a programming question but an installation issue

Comment: answered on duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50477318/cygwin-import-numpy-error